# SfDataGrid overlapping with existing content using MAUI and .NET 7

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-7.0, sfdatagrid

I've created a table using the `SfDataGrid` plugin as well as a standard `Stacklayout` template to load other data.

I've contained both in a `<Grid>`. Both load, however, they load on top of each other / under the table

The general Hierarchy of the page is as follows

```
<Grid>
      //declare Grid and following columns
      <syncfusion:SfDataGrid>

            <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>

            </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>

    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>
    
       
   //Declare Dropdowns and filters contained in a StackLayout
 
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5">
    </StackLayout>

 </Grid>
```

This image demonstrates the issue occurring. As you can see the secondary data(the dropdowns) overlap on top of the table data, where it should be positioned at the bottom

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjF53.png)

Comment: if you don't specify a row/column an element in a Grid will be placed in 0,0, even if there are other elements already there

Comment: @Jason what would be the general syntax for this ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the Row and Column each element should appear in, otherwise they will be placed on top of one another in 0,0.  This is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid?view=net-maui-7.0#rows-and-columns)

```
<Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that you can adjust the place of the `the dropdowns` at the bottom of the `SfDataGrid`.

**#1 Solution:**

```
 <Grid > 

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">

             //SfDataGrid  Control
        
        </Grid >


        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" >

             <Button Text="test" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="20"/>
         
        </Grid>

</Grid >
```

**Note:** I used a `Button` to replace Dropdowns and filters contained in a `StackLayout`. You can replace it back with Dropdowns and filters.

**#2 Solution:**

Set `VerticalOptions="End"` like below:

```
 <Grid > 
        <Grid >
             //SfDataGrid  Control
        </Grid >


        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
            
             <Button Text="test" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="20"></Button>

        </StackLayout>

</Grid >
```